# What will be the antiderivative of the function $f$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm looking for the antiderivative of $f$ on the whole $\mathbb{R}$, not only in a part of it.

$f(x) := \cases{1-x^2 ,\, \text{if}\, |x|\le 1 \\ 1+|x|, \text{if }1<|x|} \,.$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\vert x\vert\le 1$ in the first line?

Comment: yes, thank you, I've edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of your function reads:

$$x\mapsto f(x)=\begin{cases}
1-x &\text{ if } x< -1\\
1-x^{2} &\text{ if } -1\le x\le1\\
1+x &\text{ if } x>1
\end{cases}$$

A [necessary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_(analysis)) (but not sufficient) condition for a function to admit antiderivatives is to respect the intermediate value property, that is:

> Let $g:\text{dom }g\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function. $g$ is said to respect the intermediate value property if for any closed interval $[a,b]\subset\text{ dom }g$, and any $C\in[\min\{g(a),g(b)\},\max\{g(a),g(b)\}]$, there exists $c\in [a,b]$ such that $g(c)=C$.

Here, this condition does not hold. Indeed, take $a=-1.5,b=1/4$. Then, $f(a)=3.5$ and $f(b)=15/16$. If you take $C=3/2\in (15/16\,,\,3.5)$, you see that $c\in (-1.5\,,\,1/4)$ has to be such that $f(c)=1-c^{2}=3/2$, i.e. $c^{2}=-1/2$, which is not possible, or $f(c)=1-c=3/2$, i.e. $c=1/2\notin (-1.5\,,\,1/4)$.